# Regex in php - letters and numbers with limited length

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How do I make a regex that enforces:

- letters AND numbers (at least 1 of each)
- min and max length (10 to 50)
- nothing other than letters or numbers

when using a php preg_match?

---

Here's what I got:

```
 ^[A-Za-z0-9]{10,50}$
```

It seems to do everything except enforce letters AND numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do:

```
^(?=.*(?:[A-Za-z].*\d|\d.*[A-Za-z]))[A-Za-z0-9]{10,50}$
```

- `(?=.*(?:[A-Za-z].*\d|\d.*[A-Za-z]))` is zero width positive lookahead, this makes sure there is at least one letter, and one digit present
- `[A-Za-z0-9]{10,50}` makes sure the match only contains letters and digits

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X8frN8/2)

---

Or even cleaner, use two lookaheads instead of OR-ing (thanks to [chris85](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4333555/chris85)):

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z0-9]{10,50}$
```

Comment: thanks it works bro, I just checked this on the same site

Comment: I'll add this here, https://regex101.com/r/TTeWKd/1, can use 2 look aheads the don't need the `or` and duplicated character check.